# Multiple color bounding-boxes for different category objects

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I am implementing "BBAVectors-Oriented-Object-Detection" https://github.com/yijingru/BBAVectors-Oriented-Object-Detection model. After testing the model, all the detected objects are shown with same colour bounding-boxes.

Following is the link to the test.py code https://github.com/yijingru/BBAVectors-Oriented-Object-Detection/blob/master/test.py. I figured out the following line of code changes the bounding boxes colour.

```
ori_image = cv2.drawContours(ori_image, [np.int0(box)], -1, (255,0,255),1,1)
```

However, it only takes a single colour at a time.

In addition, in another file "dataset_dota.py" of "BBAVectors-Oriented-Object-Detection" https://github.com/yijingru/BBAVectors-Oriented-Object-Detection/blob/master/datasets/dataset_dota.py I found the assigned colours to each objects category.

```
class DOTA(BaseDataset):
    def __init__(self, data_dir, phase, input_h=None, input_w=None, down_ratio=None):
        super(DOTA, self).__init__(data_dir, phase, input_h, input_w, down_ratio)
        self.category = ['plane',
                         'baseball-diamond',
                         'bridge',
                         'ground-track-field',
                         'small-vehicle',
                         'large-vehicle',
                         'ship',
                         'tennis-court',
                         'basketball-court',
                         'storage-tank',
                         'soccer-ball-field',
                         'roundabout',
                         'harbor',
                         'swimming-pool',
                         'helicopter'
                         ]
        self.color_pans = [(204,78,210),
                           (0,192,255),
                           (0,131,0),
                           (240,176,0),
                           (254,100,38),
                           (0,0,255),
                           (182,117,46),
                           (185,60,129),
                           (204,153,255),
                           (80,208,146),
                           (0,0,204),
                           (17,90,197),
                           (0,255,255),
                           (102,255,102),
                           (255,255,0)]
        self.num_classes = len(self.category)
        self.cat_ids = {cat:i for i,cat in enumerate(self.category)}
        self.img_ids = self.load_img_ids()
        self.image_path = os.path.join(data_dir, 'images')
        self.label_path = os.path.join(data_dir, 'labelTxt')
```

I am fresher in Python and Opencv. I will be thankful if someone can help me to link these files and show the detected objects in different colour bounding boxes or another method to show the different object categories in different colour bounding boxes. Thank you

In the current version the detected objects are shown as follows:

[detected samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vtj9l.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet :

```py
# Initialize the DOTA Class 
dota_object = DOTA(data_dir, phase)

# Get color 
object = 'plane'
id = dota_object.category.index(object)
color = dota_object.color_pans[id]

# Display the image
ori_image = cv2.drawContours(ori_image, [np.int0(box)], -1, color,1,1)
```

Replace the variables with the ones in your code (`ori_image`,`dota_object`,`data_dir`,`phase`)

Comment: Thanks, I followed your suggestion and faced another issue. If `object = 'plane'` still the model detect objects with a single colour bounding-boxes. I have done some modifications.
```
object = dota_object.category
#object= ['plane', 'baseball-diamond', ... , 'helicopter' ]
id = dota_object.category.index(object)
color = dota_object.color_pans[id]
```
I tried two ways to assign the list of categories to `object`, but got the following error, ValueError: ['plane', 'baseball-diamond', ..., 'helicopter'] is not in list.

Any idea to solve this error??

Comment: Replace the 'plane' with the output of your model, so lets say the predictions of your model is saved in a list called pred and the first element is the predicted class something like `['plane',(x1,y1),(x2,y2)]`  then do `object=pred[0]`(this is an example change this according to your code)